# How to I know parent padding from custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I create a custom view and added it to layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.eleks.customview"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <com.eleks.customview.CView
            android:id="@+id/circle1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            custom:textSize="@dimen/circle_text_size"
            custom:text="@string/circle_default_text"
            custom:radius="@dimen/circle_radius"
            custom:textColor="@color/circle_text"
            custom:textBackground="@color/circle_background" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I implement onMeasure in custom view and set width and height. But my view ignores parent padding (20dp). See the picture:

[image]

public class CView extends View
{
    private static final String TAG = "CView";

```
// default value
private static final int DEFAULT_RADIUS = 30;
private static final int DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE = 12;
private static final int DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
private static final int DEFAULT_BACKGROUND = Color.GRAY;
private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = DEFAULT_RADIUS * 2;
private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = DEFAULT_RADIUS * 2;

// variables
private Paint mBackgroundPaint = null;
private Paint mTextPaint = null;
private float mCircleX = 0;
private float mCircleY = 0;
private float mTextX = 0;
private float mTextY = 0;
private int mWidth = DEFAULT_WIDTH;
private int mHeight = DEFAULT_HEIGHT;

// attrs
private int mTextColor = DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR;
private int mBackground = DEFAULT_BACKGROUND;
private float mRadius = DEFAULT_RADIUS;
private String mText = null;
private float mTextSize = 0;

public CView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    Log.d(TAG, "init view");
    init(null);
}

public CView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    Log.d(TAG, "init view");
    init(attrs);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attrs)
{
    if (attrs != null)
    {
        TypedArray a = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleButton, 0, 0);
        try
        {
            mTextColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleButton_textColor, DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR);
            mBackground = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleButton_textBackground, DEFAULT_BACKGROUND);
            mRadius = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CircleButton_radius, DEFAULT_RADIUS);
            mText = a.getString(R.styleable.CircleButton_text);
            mTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.styleable.CircleButton_textSize, DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE);
        }
        finally
        {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }
    mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
    mBackgroundPaint.setColor(mBackground);

    this.setMinimumHeight((int) mRadius * 2);
    this.setMinimumWidth((int) mRadius * 2);
}

private void initLayoutParams()
{
    LayoutParams params = this.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = mWidth + getLeft();
    params.height = mHeight + getTop();
    Log.d(TAG, "params| width: " + mWidth + " height: " + mHeight);
}

private void initText()
{
    mTextPaint = new Paint();
    mTextPaint.setColor(mTextColor);
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
    Rect textRect = new Rect();
    if (mText == null)
    {
        mText = "";
    }
    mTextPaint.getTextBounds(mText, 0, mText.length(), textRect);
    mTextX = mCircleX - (((Math.abs(textRect.right) - Math.abs(textRect.left))) / 2);
    mTextY = mRadius + ((Math.abs(textRect.top) - (Math.abs(textRect.bottom))) / 2);
    Log.d(TAG, "text| x: " + mTextX + " y: " + mTextY);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Log.d(TAG, "init onDraw");

    if (canvas != null)
    {
        canvas.drawCircle(mCircleX, mCircleY, mRadius, mBackgroundPaint);
        // canvas.drawText(mText, mTextX, mTextY, mTextPaint);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    // super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    Log.d(TAG, "init onMeasure");
    setWidth(MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec));
    setHeight(MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
    mCircleX = getLeft() - getPaddingLeft() + mRadius;
    mCircleY = getTop() - getPaddingTop() + mRadius;
    fixedSize();
    Log.d(TAG, "circle| x: " + mCircleX + " y: " + mCircleY);
    this.setMeasuredDimension(mWidth, mHeight);
    // initText();

}

private void fixedSize()
{
    if (mWidth > mHeight)
    {
        mHeight = mWidth;
    }
    else if (mHeight > mWidth)
    {
        mWidth = mHeight;
    }
}

private void setWidth(final int modeWidth, final int width)
{
    switch (modeWidth)
    {
        case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            Log.d(TAG, "width mode is AT_MOST");
            if (mRadius > 0)
            {
                mWidth = (int) (mRadius * 2) + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
            }
            else
            {
                mWidth = DEFAULT_WIDTH;
            }
            mWidth = Math.min(mWidth, width);
            break;
        case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            Log.d(TAG, "width mode is EXACTLY");
            break;
        case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        default:
            Log.d(TAG, "width mode is UNSPECIFIED");
            mWidth = DEFAULT_WIDTH;
            break;
    }
}

private void setHeight(final int modeHeight, final int height)
{
    switch (modeHeight)
    {
        case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            Log.d(TAG, "height mode is AT_MOST");
            if (mRadius > 0)
            {
                mHeight = (int) (mRadius * 2) + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
            }
            else
            {
                mHeight = DEFAULT_HEIGHT;
            }
            mHeight = Math.min(mHeight, height);
            break;
        case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            Log.d(TAG, "height mode is EXACTLY");
            break;
        case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        default:
            Log.d(TAG, "height mode is UNSPECIFIED");
            mHeight = DEFAULT_HEIGHT;
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
{
    // super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    Log.d(TAG, "init onLayout");
    initLayoutParams();
}
```

How can I get parent's padding?

Comment: how would the parent's padding affect your view???

Comment: Yes, parent's padding affect my view. It's problem.

Comment: So i think you should read View documentation, section "Size, padding and margin"

Comment: I read documentation and I see code from SDK, but I don't find decision.

Comment: ok, so i dont really think you need parents padding, but if you do then use getParent() to get parents View

Comment: Thanks, I'm stupid =). I know `getParent()` method, but I forgot that `ViewGroup` implements interface `ViewParent` and I cast it: `ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) getParent(); view.getPaddingLeft();`. Please answer my question so I can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: i still insist that you should not need parents padding :'(

Comment: I need padding add to width and height, else will be like my screenshot.

Comment: ok, so i run your code and everything is ok, except one thing: when calculating mCircleX/Y remove getLeft/getTop, to see it set android:background for both LinearLayout and your CView (of course to different colors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use getParent() but imho if you need it there is some design flaw

Comment: check for @Viacheslav comment to the question for the detailed answer.

Comment: @Irfan what do you mean? what comment?

Comment: in comments of the question it have some detailed explanation. I am pointing to that.

Answer (score 0):

The padding of the parent view is measured by the parent. You are not supposed to take it into account. You SHOULD, however, take into account YOUR custom widget padding. The code doesn't work because your measure does not do what it is supposed to do. I didn't check the rest of the code but probably you did other mistakes too).

`onMeasure()` is supposed to compute the size of your view and set it in `setMeasuredDimension()`.

If you want to develop custom views you should read the official documentation. In this case the [`onMeasure(int, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int,%20int)) method documentation. I also advice reading about [how Android draw views](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html).

And possibly look at the code of some widget on github or some standard Android view to see how they measure the view. (LinearLayout and RelativeLayout are good, and very different, example for ViewGroups) while ImageView is a nice complete example for a Widget.

Even if you are not writing a ViewGroup seeying how it works is helpful to understand what it does expect from a child view. The idea is that it can (and often is) a multi-step passage where the parent try to fit the child into itself by passing different constraint.

Think of it like this: measureSpecs (the parameters you receive) tells you if you are supposed to take all the space you want, if you should fit into a specific size or be EXACTLY that specific size, both in width and height. Your widget is supposed to follow those constraint and call `setMeasuredDimension()` with whichever measure you have computed.

In your case it should be `2 * radious + padding` unless this is more then the space given from the parent view.

That said, if you want to draw a circle a custom view is not really the way to go, but I guess you were just trying to learn how to build custom views.